# Download file from POST request using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, download

I have a page with "export to excel" button and i want to do that in node.js. I used DevTools in Chrome to find out, that the page downloads the file after post request, so i need to recreate it.

[image: chrome screenshot]

```
var request = require('request'),
fs = require('fs');

request.post(
    'http://pif.investfunds.ru/analitics/coefficients/',
    { form: { rmShowFunds: 'true',
              strFundName: '',
              sbxFundID: '',
              sbxObjFundInvest: '',
              SR: 'on',
              Srtn: 'on',
              date: '2016-06-30',
              Save2XLS: '1' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

I think, that i should use something like
`request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))`

but i don't understand, how.

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right. So you code would be like:

```
request.post(
        'http://pif.investfunds.ru/analitics/coefficients/',
        {
            form: {
                rmShowFunds: 'true',
                strFundName: '',
                sbxFundID: '',
                sbxObjFundInvest: '',
                SR: 'on',
                Srtn: 'on',
                date: '2016-06-30',
                Save2XLS: '1'
            }
        }
    )
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // error handling
    })
    .on('finish', function(err) {
        // request is finished
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filename.xls'));
```

Comment: Thanks, file was created, but it cannot be opened. I added console.log('File downloaded!'); to .on('finish'), but event never fires.

Comment: Does `error` event fire? Do you control remote server to view what exactly request received?

Comment: No, nothing happened. No, how can i? I opened that downloaded file, it has some data, but i think, it has incorrect format or something

Comment: I've just ran the code above and it works fine (only thing you should replace `finish` with `response` event, but it doesn't matter for downloading itself).  So I've received file with size 74752 that contains table with some data (name, percents). Do you execute some extra code? What is your environment?

Comment: Yeah, sure, size is 74752, i opened it, it has cp1251 encoding. I use atom editor on mac. So, the last thing is how to read that downloaded xls file into an array. `var workbook = xls.readFile('funds.xls');` gives an error "Unsupported file". But, i think, nevermind, either way i'll lose this hackathon ;)